# Laravel 4.2 strange routing issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, routes

Basically, I tried to upload a file and after the app created a folder inside public, every action routed me to localhost/videos. Then whenever I delete the folder it created, the behavior reverts to normal. How can creating a folder inside public which isn't even in the app folder mess up the routing? I am using Laravel 4.2 and PHP 5.5.10.

This is what I did:

```
$filename = date('Y-m-d-H:i:s')."-".$client_file_name;
$destinationPath = base_path() . '\public\uploaded_video';
Input::file('post')->move($destinationPath, $filename);
```

the second line messes up the routing and then everything becomes back to normal when I delete the folder. Is it because I am running on Windows or something? I tried doing '/public/uploaded_video' instead, but I think it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `any_Path` function returns the local path on the server but you need a `url` so in this case, you may try something like this:

```
$destinationPath = asset('uploaded_video');
```

More on [Laravel website](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/helpers#urls).

Comment: The problem was that I created a document called videos, which mirrored my route's name. That's why. I changed the name of the folder to storage and it fixed the problem. Very weird problem.